# Find constant in system of function equations

Tags: functions, functional-equations

> **Question:** Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Find all possible values of $a$ such that there exists a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(x + 2) = -f(x)$ and $f(x + 3) = f(x) + a$ for any real number $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

**My (maybe wrong) solution**:

Start listing down some values of $f(x)$ with $f(2) = -f(0)$ and $f(3) = f(0) + a$.

$f(2) + f(3) = - f(0) + f(0) + a = a$.

Similarly, you can write $f(1) = -(f(-1))$ and $f(2) = f(-1) + a$.

Hence, $f(1) + f(2) = -(f(-1)) + f(-1) + a = a$.

So, $f(1) + f(2) = f(2) + f(3) \Longrightarrow f(1) = f(3).$

But, according to the problem, $f(x + 2) = -f(x) \Longrightarrow f(3) = -f(1)$.

Since $f(1) = f(3)$ and $f(1) = -f(3) \Longrightarrow f(1) = f(3) = 0.$

Doing similar steps, we find out that $f(0) = f(2) = 0$. Hence, $a = f(2) + f(3) = 0 + 0 = 0$.

The only possible value of $a$ is $\boxed{0}$.

$\\$

If I'm doing something wrong, can someone please explain? Thanks in advance!

(Thanks to the answers, I now know I only need to prove that $a = 0$ can satisfy a valid function :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your argument is fine - so far.

While looking for **necessary** conditions for $a$, we might but conclude more about $f$ by morking slightly more generally: We have
$$ f(x+6)=-f(x+4)=f(x+2)=-f(x)$$
and
$$ f(x+6)=f(x+3)+a=f(x)+2a$$
so by equating,
$$-f(x)=f(x)+2a $$
which shows that $f$ is *necessarily* constant. But then $a=f(x+2)=-f(x)=-a$ shows that in fact $a$ is *necessarily* $=0$.

What is left (and what is also missing from your attempt!), is to show that this is also **sufficient**, i.e., that for $a=0$ there actually does exist such a function.
Fortunately, this last step is not hard - all you have to check is that for $a=0$, the constant-zero function fulfills the functional equations.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Yes, checking if a = 0 does actually give a function is not hard, you just plug it in. Your solution is similar to gt6989b's solution and both are very good. Thanks!

Comment: +1, nice addition on sufficiency

Answer (score 3):

This makes sense. Here is a different approach leading to the same place. Note that using the first relationship,
$$
f(x+6) = -f(x+4) = f(x+2) = -f(x)
$$
and using the second relationship,
$$
f(x+6) = f(x+3)+a = f(x) + 2a,
$$
so we have $f(x)+2a = -f(x) \iff f(x) = -a$, so $f$ is constant.

Now from the first relationship,
$$
-f(x) = f(x+2) = f(x) \iff f(x) = 0 \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}.
$$